# python csv - cannot save multiple lines from a string to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I have some difficulty in saving a csv file that should contain multiple lines from a string that is built from 2 strings, and when saved, the file "breaks" the last line into several lines + adds "" around a comma that is present in the file (like that ",")

Would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks!

I've tried to write the file in various methods, such as
1. for loop to write into the file
2. combine both "with open" in the code to 1
3. open an read the file with 'wb' (as bytes).

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

with open(updated_file+'.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    for row in csv_file:
        list1.append(row.split()[0])
        not_seperated = (row[:6])
        seperated = (([not_seperated[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(not_seperated), 2)]))
        seperator = "-"
        joined = seperator.join(seperated)
        print(joined)


with open(updated_file + '.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    for row in csv_file:
        list2.append(row.split()[0])
        name = (row[6:])
        print(name)

    joinedlist = joined + name
    print(joinedlist)
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(joinedlist)
```

The expected result should be a CSV file that will contain something as follows:
12-34-56,name of person (newline)
10-20-30,another name of person (newline)
....

Comment: You should not use mode `r+` with text files. Read and write the file in separate steps.

Comment: You are reading the csv-file not with the csv-module. Therefore `,` is no special character while reading but is escaped when writing.